# Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint, create-react-app

Currently starting up the server on my client side, the error above is what I have been
getting. I am using TypeScript, ReactJS, ESLint. I can't seem to go forward since this error
has been haunting me. The [GitHub page for ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) hasn't been of much help either.

This error went up after I had created the useMutation component and exported it in `index.ts`.
Not sure how to get rid of this error.

```
Below is my package.json
```

```
    {
    "name": "tinyhouse_client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
      "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
      "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
      "@types/react": "^16.9.35",
      "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.2",
      "react": "^16.13.1",
      "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
      "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
      "typescript": "~2.23.0"
      },
      "resolutions": {
     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.23.0",
     "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.23.0",
     "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^2.23.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     " build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
     "extends": "react-app"
     },
     "browserslist": {
     "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
      "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
     ]
     },
     **strong text** "proxy": "http://localhost:9000"
      }
```

```
Below is my index.ts
```

```
    export * from './server';
    export * from './useQuery';
    export * from './useMutation';
```

```
And my useMutation.ts
```

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import { server } from './server';

    interface State<TData> {
    data: TData | null;
    loading: boolean; 
    error: boolean;
    }

    type MutationTuple<TData, TVariables> = [
    (variables?: TVariables | undefined) => Promise<void>,
    State<TData>
    ];

    export const useMutation = <TData = any, TVariables = any>(
    query: string
    ): MutationTuple<TData, TVariables> => { 
    const [state, setState] = useState<State<TData>>({
    data: null,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    })

    const fetch = async (variables?: TVariables) => {
    try {
      setState({ data: null, loading: true, error: false });

      const { data, errors } = await server.fetch<TData, TVariables>({ query, variables });
      if (errors && errors.length) {
        throw new Error(errors[0].message);
      }

      setState({ data, loading: false, error: false });
    } catch (err) {
      setState({ data: null, loading: false, error: true });
      throw console.error(err);
    }
   }

   return [fetch, state];
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/Jonathanh7/tinyhouse_v1, here is the link to my github repo so you can see that errors I have been getting on your Editors.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825685/if-i-use-a-typescript-tuple-in-my-react-app-i-get-a-eslint-error-on-line-1-in-vs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is this coming from eslint-typescript? If so, check that your version of typescript is not a dev/nightly build.

Comment: For me this was solved by downgrading typescript to <4.0, removing `node_modules` and lock file. Something with create-react-app doesn't support ts 4 yet it seems like.

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct answer for all cases. Regardless of versions of tslint or Typescript problem is in wrong types. Check this: `myValue: [][]` versus `myValue: string[][]`. Check answers below.

Comment: I made this the answer since the version I was previously using was a nightly build. Downgrading it to a none nightly build solved my issue.

Answer (score 110):

**Edit:** as noted by Meng-Yuan Huang, this issue no longer occurs in `react-scripts@^4.0.1`

This error occurs because `react-scripts` has a direct dependency on the 2.xx range of `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`.

You can fix this by adding a resolutions field to your `package.json` as follows:

```
"resolutions": {
  "**/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
  "**/@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1"
}
```

**NPM users:** add the resolutions field above to your `package.json` but use [npx npm-force-resolutions](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions) to update package versions in `package-lock.json`.

**Yarn users:** you don't need to do anything else. See [selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) for more info.

NOTE: if you're using a monorepo/Yarn workspaces, the `resolutions` field must be in the top-level `package.json`.

NOTE: `yarn add` and `yarn upgrade-interactive` don't respect the `resolutions` field and they can generate a `yarn.lock` file with incorrect versions as a result. Watch out.

Comment: see also https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2260#issuecomment-681288735

Comment: Thank you! I also had the problem that my returned tuple type `[string, string]` gave the error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. This unhelpful message drove me crazy until I found this.

Comment: Thanks for your information. However, I fix this problem by updating react-scripts from 3.4.4 to 4.0.1.

Answer (score 95):

Your version of TypeScript is not compatible with your eslint. You can fix it by upgrading these two dependencies to the latest version.

**TypeScript 4.0.5** is compatible with version 4.6.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.0",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.1.5** is compatible with version 4.18.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.2.4** is compatible with version 4.23.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.23.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.23.0",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.3.2** is compatible with version 4.25.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.25.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.25.0",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.5.5** is compatible with version 5.10.2

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.6.2** is compatible with version 5.15.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.15.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.15.0",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.7.2** is compatible with version 5.26.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0",
}
```

**TypeScript 4.9.5** is compatible with version 5.56.0

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.56.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.56.0",
}
```

Comment: I could not find a resource describing the correct versions to use. In case you have one, it would be great to add the link.

Comment: I update my dependencies and when I see it working then I update this answer

Comment: For me did not fixed my issue, but I am aware that is definitely something related with conflict with versions between Typescript and eslint

Answer (score 74):

For future Googlers:

I had the same issue just now on TypeScript 4.0.2 in a Vue.js 2 project. I fixed it by upgrading `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` to the latest that npm would give me using `@latest`, which at the time was 3.3.0 and 3.10.1, respectively.

Comment: Although this won't work if you are using an unejected Create React App bootstrapped project.

Comment: Hi @JohannesKlauß ! were you able to find out how could you solve this issue with an unejected Create React App project? I am still getting this error. Thanks!

Comment: Haven't checked yet, but you should be able to force a single version via the `resolutions` field inside the package.json https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Comment: Hi again @JohannesKlauß thank you for your response! I finally changed my typescript version to 3.9.5 and the error stopped.

Comment: You can also subscribe to this issue here to track the progress: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9515

Comment: @JohannesKlauß Thanks for the tip, it seems that yarn resolutions don't do any justice either. It's still throwing an error, even by specifying `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser` to `4.0.1`. Had to revert back to 3.9.7 and delete the .cache folder as others said.

Comment: I think every version < 4 should work. The vital part is the fresh install, so no cache is used.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß I also had to revert to 3.9.7 and delete my node_modules directory.

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2446#issuecomment-683969845 This helps me to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 56):

Try playing around with variable types inside the interfaces.
E. g I've got this error when I had such state interface:

```
interface State{
    foo: []
}
```

but when I've changed the type of array it worked:

```
interface State{
    foo: string[]
}
```

Comment: This fixes the bug because `[]` is parsed as a tuple type, while `string[]` is pared as an array type. In TS 4.0 a property was renamed on the tuple type node in the AST that breaks this. So a possible quick way around the error is to just avoid tuple types if able...

Comment: @DavidSherret's comment and this answer were what worked for me. Updating the `eslint-plugin` and `parser` had no affect. But, reworking the type definition resolve the issue.

Comment: Extremely useful, this fixed my issues!

Comment: Also replacing [number, number] with number[] as well as other types fixes the remaining errors.

Comment: very helpful, I had similar issue, where I declared an array without specifying the type.

Answer (score 28):

This is what worked for my CRA project.

Step 1: edit `package.json` and set `typescript` version to `^3.9.7`

Step 2: delete `.cache` folder in `node_modules`

Step 3: run `npm install`

Comment: It fixed after deleting the .cache folder

Comment: This helped, but I ran into issues with Babel after too, so deleting the whole `node_modules` directory solved both.

Comment: I also had to remove the entire `node_modules` directory for this to work

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes this error is a result of an invalid type as others have stated

I've gotten this error when using a bare array as a type

```
const someVariable: [] //Incorrect
const someVariable: string[] //Correct
```

I also got this error when typing an multidimensional array incorrectly:

```
const someVariable : [string[]] //Incorrect. Results in map error

const someVariable : string[][] //Correct
```

The error message from typescript is pretty cryptic so hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same error but the fix for me was that I had one of the type as

```
text : string[] | []
```

and changing it to

```
text : string[]
```

worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Also except `array types` problems describing im answers above, there are many `tuple` cases cause this problem.. Let me mention them

```
interface Some {
  // error
  tupleValue: [string, number]

  // works
  tupleValue: [v1: string, v2: number]

  // error
  tupleArr: [v1: string, v2: number][] 

  // works!
  tupleArr2: Array<[v1: string, v2: number]>
}
```

another case:

```
type ValueView = [value: SomeObj, view: string]

// error
const res1: ValueView[] = arr.map(v => [v, v.name])
// works !!!
const res: ValueView[] = arr.map(v => [v, v.name] as ValueView)

// error
const res = arr.map(v => [v, v.name] as [SomeObj, string])
// works !!!
const res = arr.map(v => [v, v.name] as [value: SomeObj, view: string])
```

So check your tuple operations twice

Answer (score 3):

for all the guys who is using create-react-app and typescript.

when you encounting some Error like this

upgrade typescript

and

upgrade react-script package

Answer (score 3):

In case you have dynamically typed function arguments, and Typescript v4 and up, this error may occur. I had

```
{
  ...
    getDataThunk: (...args: [string]) => dispatch(getData(...args))
  ...
}
```

This error had never been thrown till I was using TS version <= 4.0.0. Also, Having spread arguments was quite an over-engineering for me, replacing it with exact comma separated function arguments resolved the said issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was found this problem and I solve it with change value type in the file

**in my case** I was declare a

```
let data: [] = [];
```

and all of my file is error show Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when I change to

```
let data: any = [];
```

It's was work and error was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn users, I had the same problem in react, I solved the problem by removing the package-lock.json file and installing again:

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

I'd made with vscode closed by linux terminal, to don't have problem with cache.

Comment: If you remove `package.json`, `yarn install` won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add the dependencies manually, even when it gave a warning of incompatibility, because the `npm-force-resolutions` solution did not work for me.

1. First, I had to add the following dependencies to `package.json` (`dependencies` because I'm using create-react-app, which I have never seen to use `devDependencies`):

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
}
```

2. Then, I do `rm -rf node_modules/` so I can have a clean install of npm stuff.
3. Next, install everything: `npm install`.
4. Check that you have the correct version: `npm ls @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`. It said `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` but I had to ignore it because otherwise I could not get this working.
5. `npm start` to make sure the create-react-app now works.

I'd advice going for the npm-force-resolutions solution first, but if it fails try this one.

**Oh, and one extra note:**

This entire disaster was because I did something like this:

```js
interface SomeInterface {
  someBoolean: boolean,
  someList: number[],
  someTuple: [string, string]  // <-- THIS is the problem
}
```

If I removed that commented line, the code would compile without issues. I kept it that way because I had already made my code to work like that, but if you just avoid having a tuple inside the interface (didn't matter if it had [labels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#labeled-tuple-elements) or not), you can potentially avoid all this hassle.

Comment: no need to avoid use tuples, just write `someTuple: [v1: string, v2: string]` to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I had a property in the react.props interface lie this

```
someName: [];
```

changing it to

```
someName: any[];
```

fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this in your package.json as follows:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
```

and my typescript version is: "typescript": "^4.1.5"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add two dependencies to "resolutions" in my package.json.

```js
"resolutions": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.0"
}
```

And I'm using Typescript 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was facing was that I tried to export a type with an a property that was an interface.

After looking one by one, I found that I was using an interface inside a type. So I had to change it back to an interface and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Updating eslint, plugin and the parser worked for me

```bash
npm i eslint@latest @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest @typescript-eslint/parser@latest
```