# Syntax error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (0:undefined) build on aws amplify

Tags: reactjs

I am facing the following error while building on AWS amplify:

> Syntax error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (0:undefined)

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';   
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
export default class BusinessHTTPService {
static getBusinessList = () => {
  
    return axios.get(`${API_BASE}business-categories/?`).then(response => response.data);
  };
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While I am building code on AWS it's throwing an error but locally when I am running the code its working fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079477/line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with by build failing on AWS Amplify Console, but was fine locally.

**How to reproduce locally**

I was able to reproduce it locally by following these steps:

1. run "npm ci"
2. run "npm start"

"npm start" would fail, and show the error "Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

**How to solve**

I was able to solve it eventually by following these steps:

1. downgrade typescript from version 4.0.2 to version 3.9.7.
2. run "npm ci"
3. run "npm start"

I don't see the error anymore, and when I push to AWS Amplify Console, it builds without issues.

Comment: This helped me even though I don't use AWS Amplify. There appears to be something wrong in the TS compiler and babel/webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with this code:

```
interface Event<EventArgs extends unknown[] = []> { ... }
```

The problem disappeared when I specified the type of the array:

```
interface Event<EventArgs extends unknown[] = unknown[]> { ... }
```