# If I use a typescript tuple in my react-app i get a eslint error on line 1 in vscode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

The error is `Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I set up a new file just to reproduce the error:

```
export default () => {
  let something: [string, boolean]
  something = ['something', true];
}
```

am i missing something? all other types seem to work fine.

Comment: Your error is probably not caused by this code. However maybe you forgot to return `something` from function?

Comment: We can't reproduce your error in the code provided. please edit your question.

Comment: I have the same issue with create-react-app and Typescript. The tuple type is the problem. However I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

The problem is when you created the tuple type `[string, boolean]` this is a new way to declare types with arrays introduced in Typescript 4.0 called [Labeled Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements).

**The Solution**

Upgrade your react-scripts to v4 ([Here is the issue on their github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9515#issuecomment-714907478)). If you are using `yarn` use the command `yarn upgrade react-scripts@4.0.1`. With npm should be something similar, you can try `npm install react-scripts@4.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

If i right understand you, here is your solution (you don't have to create a let in order to register the types, but directly in the function specify which types it will return)

```
// main.ts
export default (): [string, boolean] => {
 return ["something", true];
};
```

And if you need to call this code, you just create such a component(example):

```
import foo from "./main.ts"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {foo().map(el =>
        <div>
          {el}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it appears that the issue is with using the `let` keyword.
I was experiencing this when converting to TS after using `let` in just JavaScript a bunch of times without a hitch, but changing to `const` fixed it down the line.

Here are some intricacies between `let` and `const` detailed on the TypeScript website: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#let-vs-const