# Mysterious compile error "Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when not using map

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created the following useToggle hook which does not make use of `.map()`:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useToggle = (
  initialValue: boolean = false
): [boolean, () => void] => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const toggleValue = () => setValue((prevVal) => !prevVal);

  return [value, toggleValue];
};
```

The TS compiler gives me the following error:

```
./src/Components/util/hooks/useToggle.ts
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I've searched for the word map in the file like 10 times, but it's not there. Someone please reassure me I'm not going insane!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079477/line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

Comment: The solution was to reinstall `node_modules`

Answer (score -1):

The solution was simpler than I imagined:

Step 1: delete `node_modules`

Step 2: `npm install`

Step 3: error gone