# Parsing error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map) - Angular/Eslint

Tags: angular, typescript, terminal, eslint

I'm trying to use the eslint command on my angular project in the terminal to check a typescript component for errors. I'm getting an error that I don't know what to do about since it states the error is on line 0 and utilizing `eslint '**/**.ts' --fix` doesn't change anything.

This is the error after using `eslint 'src/app/admin/file.ts' in the terminal`:

`0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

I've checked for spelling errors on the file, but there are none. Everywhere I look for this error online links to an error with (Eslint, React, Typescript) and the solution entails `react-scripts` and adding the `resolution` property on package.json. [Link to other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079477/line-0-parsing-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined)

I'd like to be able to run the eslint command without getting an error, any suggestions would be helpful.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node git.version.js",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json --configuration=development",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "pretest": "node git.version.js",
    "pretest:ci": "node git.version.js",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false --progress=false",
    "test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --progress=false --code-coverage",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "compodoc": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.doc.json -s",
    "installGoogleFonts": "goog-webfont-dl -a -f Roboto -d vendor/fonts -o vendor/roboto.css -p './fonts/'",
    "prebuild:metagraph": "node git.version.js && node inject-env-vars.js",
    "build:metagraph": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --source-map --configuration=metagraph",
    "postinstall": "node patch.js",
    "eslint": "eslint 'src/**/*.ts' --fix --cache"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.14",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "^9.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^2.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^9.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.24",
    "@types/chroma-js": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/email-validator": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
    "@types/qs": "6.5.1",
    "bodybuilder": "github:cjwilsonjr/bodybuilder",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chroma-js": "^1.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.12.2",
    "d3-geo": "^1.12.1",
    "d3-geo-projection": "^2.9.0",
    "d3-selection-multi": "^1.0.1",
    "draggabilly": "^2.3.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.3",
    "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "exceljs": "^1.15.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^7.0.3",
    "ng-let": "^13.0.3",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "node": "^14.15.2",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "packery": "^2.1.2",
    "qs": "6.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "topojson": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.14",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.16",
    "@types/d3-array": "^1.2.7",
    "@types/d3-axis": "^1.0.14",
    "@types/d3-force": "^1.2.2",
    "@types/d3-hierarchy": "^1.1.7",
    "@types/d3-interpolate": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/d3-path": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/d3-scale": "^1.0.15",
    "@types/d3-selection": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.3.4",
    "@types/d3-transition": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/d3-zoom": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^2.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.34.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "fstream": ">=1.0.12",
    "goog-webfont-dl": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.14",
    "karma-angular": "0.0.6",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "karma-typescript-angular2-transform": "^4.1.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "tar": ">=6.1.9",
    "ts-essentials": "^2.0.12",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```