# Typescript compiler error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

Am getting a compiler error with typescript.

```
[tsl] ERROR in /.../node_modules/@remirror/react-components/node_modules/@mui/base/useMenu/useMenu.d.ts(3,15)
      TS1005: ',' expected.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14
```

In the file, an import is causing the error:

```
import { type MenuUnstyledContextType } from '../MenuUnstyled';

'type' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Module '"../MenuUnstyled"' has no exported member 'type'. Did you mean to use 'import type from "../MenuUnstyled"' instead?ts(2614)
```

That appears to be valid in typescript 3.8 though, and the app uses `typescript ^4.3.5` and `@babel/preset-typescript ^7.14.5`.

[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#:~:text=With%20TypeScript%203.8%2C%20you%20can,statement%2C%20or%20using%20import%20type%20](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#:%7E:text=With%20TypeScript%203.8%2C%20you%20can,statement%2C%20or%20using%20import%20type%20)

```
// Explicitly pull out a value (getResponse) and a type (APIResponseType) 
import { getResponse, type APIResponseType} from "./api";
```

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: @jabaa Not since November 2021 :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> That appears to be valid in typescript 3.8 though

Unfortunately, it isn't - [the docs you found](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types) are very much misleading.

TypeScript 3.8 [introduced type-only imports](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#type-only-imports-exports) only with the `import type …` syntax:

> *As a solution in TypeScript 3.8, we’ve added a new syntax for type-only imports and exports.*
>
> ```
> import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";
>
> export type { SomeThing };
> ```
>
> *`import type` only imports declarations to be used for type annotations and declarations. It always gets fully erased, so there’s no remnant of it at runtime. Similarly, `export type` only provides an export that can be used for type contexts, and is also erased from TypeScript’s output.*

The syntax you are looking for [was introduced with TypeScript 4.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-on-import-names):

> #### *`type` Modifiers on Import Names*
>
> [A type import] *works, but it would be nice to avoid two import statements for the same module. That’s part of why TypeScript 4.5 allows a `type` modifier on individual named imports, so that you can mix and match as needed.*
>
> ```
> import { someFunc, type BaseType } from "./some-module.js";
> export class Thing implements BaseType {
>     someMethod() {
>         someFunc();
>     }
> }
> ```

So update your version of TypeScript, or change your import declaration to

```
import type { APIResponseType } from "./api";
import { getResponse } from "./api";
```

Answer (score 2):

**TypeScript 4.5.5 is compatible with version 5.10.2**

```js
    
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626605/7166178